# How I can get Instagram email from Instagram username?

Tags: instagram

I want to know what is the email that linked to this instagram id: http://instagram.com/irshaid

I forgot if this account is for me or for who so I want to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot get email using API. Click forgot password and enter username, u will get an email.